# Using Kirchhoff to solve circuits with more than one cell source

Tags: electric-current, voltage

[image]

Hello guys, I've been trying to understand this but I'm facing difficulties. I do not know how my lecturer got those equations and why isn't any equation from "a".
Thanks guys

Comment: (1) there is only one independent KVL equation since there is just one loop (you can see that the 2nd equation is just the negative of the first equation) , (2)  I'm not sure about the "from b" and "from c".  The first equation is arrived by traversing the loop clockwise.  Traversing counterclockwise instead gives the second equation.

Comment: Your welcome.  I would add that the direction your lecturer  chose for the current can be purely arbitrary. If values are given for the voltage sources and resistors you can calculate the current. If the value of current turns out negative, it simply means the actual direction of current is opposite the one chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lecturer is simply showing two alternative ways to develop the loop equation from KVL. The second equation moves around the loop in the opposite direction from the first equation (and vice versa). Note that if you multiply either equation by a negative 1, you get the other equation. It helps if you label the polarities of the voltages across each resistor based on the chosen direction of current noting that the voltage drops (+ to -) in the direction of current flow. Take resistor r2 as an example. From b moving counter-clockwise around the loop there is a voltage drop across r2 (+ to -). Thus you have -ir2 in first equation. From C moving clockwise around the loop you have a voltage rise across r2 (- to +), thus +ir2. Ditto for the other resistors as well as the voltage sources. Hope this helps.